# 3ds Max units problem when importing STL file from SolidWorks

Tags: 3d, export, 3ds-max, units, solidworks

I'm trying to import a SolidWorks file (saved as .STL) to 3ds Max.

The shape, vertices etc. are importing correctly. But I cannot figure out how to set the units.

I made a simple 100mm x 100mx square, extruded 20mm, and saved as .STL. When I import it to 3ds Max and measure the distance between two vertices in the bottom of the square, the distance should be 100mm (or 10cm). But instead I got this:

```
"Dist: 687,993cm"
```

I used `Tools -> Measure Distance` and click on the two corner vertices to get this result.

I have already (I suppose) set units from `Customize -> Units Setup` to centimeters. So the result should be 10cm, but instead it becomes 687.993 cm. How can I fix this so I know that I'm working with the same units between solidworks and 3ds max ?

Answer (score -1):

It helps to set Customize → Units Setup → System Unit Setup to the same units as well.